# Converting files in multiple directories from tab separated to comma separated

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv, for

I am running Mac OS.

I have a directory `/Users/sethparker/Documents` containing several subdirectories `/Users/sethparker/Documents/dir1`,`/Users/sethparker/Documents/dir2`,`/Users/sethparker/Documents/dir3`. Each subdirectory is filled with identically named, tab separated files `file1.txt`,`file2.txt`,`file3.txt`.

I would like all of the files in all of the subdirectories converted to comma separated, though the extension itself does not matter. My current approach is to run a short script in each subdirectory.

```
cat tsv_to_csv.sh
```

```
for ifile in {1..3};
do
sed -i "" 's/\t/,/g' file${ifile}*
done
```

Is there an efficient way to apply this type of processing to all files in all subdirectories at once?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Is this on macOS? Please always mention your OS since both what tools are available and how those tools behave can depend on it.

Comment: Do you want to do this for all subdirectories of `/Users/sethparker/Documents/` and for all files in each subdirectory, or are there any files and or subdirs you want to skip?

Comment: @terdon I have edited the question. Yes I am on MacOS and yes all files in all subdirectories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can safely run this for *all* subdirectories and *all* files in those subdirectories, all you need is:

```
sed -i "" 's/\t/,/g' /Users/sethparker/Documents/*/*
```

Answer (score 2):

To handle the edge cases (such as tab appearing in a quoted field, or comma appearing in an *unquoted* field), a CSV parser is recommended for CSV data.

Using [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (and `sponge` from the `moreutils` package)

```bsh
for file in glob_pattern; do
    csvformat --tabs --out-delimiter , "$file" | sponge "$file"
done
```

Demo:

```bsh
$ cat input.tsv
first   "second third"  fourth
she said    Hello, world!
```

There's a quoted tab on the first line

```bsh
$ csvformat --tabs --out-delimiter , input.tsv
first,second    third,fourth
she,said,"Hello, world!"
```